# How can I add a tapGestureRecognizer with a parameter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code currently adds this in the back end C#

```cs
deselectGridLink.GestureRecognizers.Add(NewTapGestureForUpdateCategories(false));

    private TapGestureRecognizer NewTapGestureForUpdateCategories(bool val)
    {
        return new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
                App.DB.UpdateAllCategories(val);
                GetPageData();
                RemoveTableViewClickSection();
                tableView.Root.Add(CreateTableSection());
                SetPageDetails();
            })
        };
    }
```

How can I add this in XAML with the parameter of false also included. Also if I somehow add this to XAML do I need to change the C#f NewTapGestureForUpdateCategories method?:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
   <Label TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" x:Name="deselectLink" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Deselect All" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="deselectGridLink" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
    <Label TextColor="Blue" 
           Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
           x:Name="deselectLink" 
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           Text="Deselect All" >
     <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!set parameter here.
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="false"/>
     </Label.GestureRecognizers>

    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
{
    public Command TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(val => {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", val.ToString(), "OK");
            });
        }
    }

    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

When you set value on **CommandParameter** in Label.GestureRecognizers , the TapCommand in code behind can receive it .

Comment: Can you explain how the command parameter is used in the code behind.  I think you might have missed explaining that.  Thank you

Comment: @Alan2 No need to write code behind , see the `CommandParameter `, just set directly in xaml, also you can use `CommandParameter="{Binding isVal}"` ,and set the property isVal in code behind.

Comment: Hi, If you have a few minutes could you add this to the XAML and C# so it's really clear how to pass the true or false into the TapCommand or show how the TapCommand can be changed to see the true or false.  Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding UserName}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkTextColor}" FontSize="Medium" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Mobile}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkTextColor}" FontSize="Small" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="{StaticResource DarkTextColor}" FontSize="Small" />
                
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" IsVisible="{Binding IsAdmin}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        TextColor="Red" FontSize="Large"Text="&#xf2ed;" FontFamily="Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Status_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding UserId}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
async private void Status_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lblClicked = (Label)sender;
    var item = (TapGestureRecognizer)lblClicked.GestureRecognizers[0];
    var id=item.CommandParameter;
}
```